# MySQL. Issue with: INTERVAL 60 MINUTES + last_run < NOW()

Tags: mysql, sql

I am attempting to select a row from the database based on a time value.

My database contains a table of actions. These actions run ever x number of minutes. When the action is ran, the row is updated and it's `last_run` column which is a `TIMESTAMP` containing the value of `NOW()`

Here is a valid row in the database. As you can see from this row it was last run some days ago. It's set to run every 60 minutes.

[image]

I use `INTERVAL last_run + interval_minutes < NOW()`. So, the last run time, plus sixty minutes, would be less than the value of `NOW()` if 60 minutes has passed.

The query I am trying to run is below:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    routine_actions
WHERE
    routine_actions.routine_id = 12
AND 
    INTERVAL routine_actions.interval_minutes MINUTE + routine_actions.last_run < NOW()
GROUP BY routine_id
```

But, I'm getting no results. Any idea's what I could be doing wrong?

Comment: what type is interval_minutes ?

Comment: interval_minutes is an integer.

Comment: the query you're trying looks ok but `INTERVAL last_run + interval_minutes < NOW()` is wrong. `INTERVAL` should precede `interval_minutes` not `last_run`

Comment: @FuzzyTree Ah! Works fine now. Put that as answer, will accept.

Comment: DATE_ADD(routine_actions.last_run, INTERVAL routine_actions.interval_minutes MINUTE)  < NOW()

Comment: @Beep.exe I've never used DATE_ADD. Is there any difference in using DATE_ADD vs +?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query you're trying looks ok but in the first part of your question, the following

```
INTERVAL last_run + interval_minutes MINUTES < NOW()
```

should be

```
INTERVAL interval_minutes MINUTES + last_run < NOW()
```